# jquery tabs, onload event on first tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery tabs plugin and ajax json mvc to retrieve data inside these tabs.
Everything works ok with onclick events but I need to load content inside first tab as soon as  page load.
Here's the code

```
<script>
$(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        // how to add onload event for Tab One GetTabData(id); 

        $(".tabLink").click(function (event) {
            var id = $(this).parent().text();    
            GetTabData(id); 
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="demo">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab-1" tabId="1" class="tabLink">Tab One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2" tabId="2" class="tabLink">Tab Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-3" tabId="3" class="tabLink">Tab three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-4" tabId="4" class="tabLink">Tab four</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab-1">                
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2">                
        </div>
        <div id="tab-3">                
        </div>
        <div id="tab-4">                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the point of this `var id = $(this).parent().text();`? Why not just get the id from the href `$(this).attr('href').replace('#tab-','')`? `tabId` isn't a valid html attribute, and you can't (*shouldn't*) just make one up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programatically click on the first one:

```
$(".tabLink").click(function (event) {
  var id = $(this).parent().text();    
  GetTabData(id); 
}).eq(0).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to load content inside first tab ***as soon as page load***

Then load the content of the first tab on `$(document).ready()`

```
$(function(){

    ...your code...

    //execute first
    GetTabData(1); 
});
```